# Why emit signal in constructor doesnt work?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to emit signals in constructor, like this:

```
VideoStream::VideoStream(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::VideoStream)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ……  //m_deviceIP already intialized here
    emit streamReq(m_deviceIP);//emitting at here
    recentRecordReq();//this function include a emit sentence,too
}
```

But it doesnt work!
For test, I add a Button and then move the emit sentence into the slot, it works well:

```
void VideoStream::on_streamReqBtn_clicked()
{
    emit streamReq(m_deviceIP);
}
```

I don't know why.

Comment: how do you connect the signal to a slot before the constructor runs?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work"?  You also need to show us how you connect the signal to a slot.  (I suspect the answer is that you call `Connect(object1, signal1, object2, slot2)`.  If so - you probably haven't started to call `Connect` yet.)

Answer (score 11):

It does send the signal, but there's nobody to get it. In other words, when you `connect` your class instance to something else, when you're calling the `connect` method, your class instance already has been created and has sent that signal, so when you call `connect` that signal has already been sent and nobody has received it.

```
VideoStream *stream = new VideoStream; // Here the signal is emitted

// you're connecting after the signal emission 
QObject::connect(stream, &VideoStream::streamReq, /* ... */)
```