# Can't receive signal in qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals, signals-slots

I've connected slot from class Client to signal from class ClientNetwork, but it's not working

Client class:

```
Client::Client(QString &ip, quint16 port)
{
    clientNetwork = new ClientNetwork(ip,port);
    connect(clientNetwork, &ClientNetwork::clientConnected, this, &Client::connected); 
}
void Client::connected()
{
    qDebug()<<"clientConnected signal received"; //This qDebug is not showing
}
```

And ClientNetwork class:

```
ClientNetwork::ClientNetwork(QString &hostIp, quint16 hostPort)
    : port(hostPort), ip(hostIp)
{
    ................
    ...code.........
    ................

    emit clientConnected(); // emit signal
    qDebug()<<"Client::clientConnected"; // this qDebug is showing
}
```

Why it can't receive the signal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why emit signal in constructor doesnt work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220300/why-emit-signal-in-constructor-doesnt-work)

Comment: By the time your `connect` is active ... the signal was already emitted and gone ... your connection wont catch it. You need to consider your design to avoid such unfavorable scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are emitting signal clientConnected() before connecting Client to ClientNetwork.
You can solve this by making connection on ClientNetwork Construct before emitting any clientConnected() signal and by passing Client pointer or reference to ClientNetwork constructor BUT I DON'T RECOMMEND DOING THIS.

The best way is to remove all connection processing from constructor and to create in your ClientNetwork class a "connect" method that you will call it after connecting signal/slot on Client class :

```
Client::Client(QString &ip, quint16 port)
{
  clientNetwork = new ClientNetwork(ip,port);
  connect(clientNetwork, &ClientNetwork::clientConnected, this, &Client::connected); 
  clientNetwork->connect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the the constructor of the `class Client` is invoked, it first creates a `ClientNetwork` where you already emit the signal `clientConnected` and only after that the connection between `ClientNetwork::ClientConnected` and `Client::connected` is established.

So basically the problem is that there is **no connection** established between the signal and the slot when the signal is emitted.

If `clientConnected()` is a public signal, then you can do the following in the constructor the `Client`:

```
Client::Client(QString &ip, quint16 port)
{
   clientNetwork = new ClientNetwork(ip,port);
   connect(clientNetwork, &ClientNetwork::clientConnected, this, &Client::connected);
   emit clientNetwork->clientConnected();
   //or call a public method of Client which does that for you depending on your design.
}
```

Comment: the problem is well explained but the fix is dirty since clientConnected() signal will be sent whatever connection success of fail.

Comment: Yes, it should ideally only be emitted when a proper connection is established, the logic for which might lie somewhere in the `ClientNetwork`. All that the OP needs to know is that the connection has to be established before any sort of signal is emitted.